# App crashed when play youtube video after navigated all screens

Tags: ios, video, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

We used tab bar controller in our app and i navigated to all view controllers(screens) and then play the youtube video then the app is crashed.

If i directly play the youtube video then no issue.

Crash Report: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/140

Comment: It seems that you can reproduce the crash. Does it crash if you do it while connected to XCode? Does the debugger console says anything to find the line of crash?

Comment: libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
    0x3a466df4 <+0>:  mov    r12, #0x148
    0x3a466df8 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x3a466dfc <+8>:  blo    0x3a466e14                ; <+32>
    0x3a466e00 <+12>: ldr    r12, [pc, #0x4]           ; <+24>
    0x3a466e04 <+16>: ldr    r12, [pc, r12]
    0x3a466e08 <+20>: b      0x3a466e10                ; <+28>
    0x3a466e0c <+24>: rsbseq r7, r0, #0x80000001
    0x3a466e10 <+28>: bx     r12
    0x3a466e14 <+32>: bx     lr

Answer (score 0):

from breakpoints screen remove exceptions if you have any
it worked for me